# Centering Leaflet divIcon marker with dynamic content

Tags: css, leaflet

I created a simple Leaflet map with markers for some countries. Currently all the markers are not centered at their middle point, but at their top left point.

This is the code I have now:

```js
const countries = [
  [52.32, 5.55, "&#127475;&#127473;&nbsp;Netherlands"],
  [50.64, 4.67, "&#127463;&#127466;&nbsp;Belgium"],
  [51, 10, "&#127465;&#127466;&nbsp;Germany"],
  [47, 2, "&#127467;&#127479;&nbsp;France"],
  [42.56, 1.56, "&#127462;&#127465;&nbsp;Andorra"],
  [40.2, -3.5, "&#127466;&#127480;&nbsp;Spain"],
  [38.7, -9.18, "&#127477;&#127481;&nbsp;Portugal"],
  [52, 19, "&#127477;&#127473;&nbsp;Poland"],
  [50, 16, "&#127464;&#127487;&nbsp;Czechia"],
  [46.8, 8.23, "&#127464;&#127469;&nbsp;Switzerland"]
];

let map = L.map("map", {
  worldCopyJump: true
}).setView({
  lat: 50,
  lon: 10
}, 5);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 10,
  attribution: "&copy; <a href=\"https://openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a>"
}).addTo(map);

L.control.scale().addTo(map);

const regions = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

countries.forEach((country) => {
  L.marker([country[0], country[1]], {
    icon: L.divIcon({
      iconSize: "auto",
      html: "<b>" + country[2] + "</b>"
    })
  }).addTo(regions);
})

map.addLayer(regions);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leaflet-div-icon {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

My expected result is that all div elements with the class name "leaflet-div-icon" are positioned half of their width to the left, and half of their height upwards. For example, look at Andorra, currently only the top left point of the marker is in Andorra, and the rest is outside it. I would like the middle point of the marker to be in Andorra.

I tried adding the following code, but this moves all markers in a wrong position:

```css
.leaflet-div-icon {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
}
```

Comment: Leaflet actually handles this “correctly” most of the time. Icon and DivIcon have an iconAnchor property that is “Centered by default if size is specified, also can be set in CSS with negative margins.” The “problem” is that you’re using auto for iconSize and leaflet doesn’t know how much to adjust it by (it centers it if you specify an explicit size). I don't have a proper solution offhand, but hopefully this helps you or someone else on the way to a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might override the default `.leaflet-div-icon` style, and then style its child `b` to look and be placed as you'd like:

```js
const countries = [
  [52.32, 5.55, "&#127475;&#127473;&nbsp;Netherlands"],
  [50.64, 4.67, "&#127463;&#127466;&nbsp;Belgium"],
  [51, 10, "&#127465;&#127466;&nbsp;Germany"],
  [47, 2, "&#127467;&#127479;&nbsp;France"],
  [42.56, 1.56, "&#127462;&#127465;&nbsp;Andorra"],
  [40.2, -3.5, "&#127466;&#127480;&nbsp;Spain"],
  [38.7, -9.18, "&#127477;&#127481;&nbsp;Portugal"],
  [52, 19, "&#127477;&#127473;&nbsp;Poland"],
  [50, 16, "&#127464;&#127487;&nbsp;Czechia"],
  [46.8, 8.23, "&#127464;&#127469;&nbsp;Switzerland"]
];

let map = L.map("map", {
  worldCopyJump: true
}).setView({
  lat: 50,
  lon: 10
}, 5);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 10,
  attribution: "&copy; <a href=\"https://openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a>"
}).addTo(map);

L.control.scale().addTo(map);

const regions = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

countries.forEach((country) => {
  L.marker([country[0], country[1]], {
    icon: L.divIcon({
      iconSize: "auto",
      html: "<b>" + country[2] + "</b>"
    })
  }).addTo(regions);
})

map.addLayer(regions);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#map .leaflet-div-icon {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map .leaflet-div-icon b {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background:#fff;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```